# if no data : Trying to get property of non-object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hı, 
when ı get data from the table;
if there is data, there is no problem but if there is no data, it gives an error

[if have data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS5tt.jpg)

[if no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWTCT.jpg)

please suggest me

my model

```
public function denemelik($tarih){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('randevular');
    $this->db->join('hasta_karti', 'randevular.h_id=hasta_karti.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('r_gun', $tarih);
    $query= $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()<1){
     return false;
    } else{
    return  $query->row();
    }
```

my controller :

```
$tarih=$this->input->post('day');
        if($tarih==""){$day=date('Y-m-d');} else {$day=$tarih;}
        $h_id="";
        $data2['randevular']        =   $this->Database_Model->denemelik($day);
        $data2['hastalar']          =   $this->Database_Model->tum_hastalar();
        $data2['r_saatleri']        =   $this->Database_Model->randevu_saatleri();
        $data2['r_tarih_list'] = $day;
        $this->load->view('admin/_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/_leftmenu');
        $this->load->view('admin/randevular_view_1', $data2);
        $this->load->view('admin/_footer');
```

and my view

```
<?php if($randevular->r_saat) { ?>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Dolu</button>
                                        <?php } else { ?> 
                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Müsait</button>
                                        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your model with this.

```
public function denemelik($tarih){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('randevular');
    $this->db->join('hasta_karti', 'randevular.h_id=hasta_karti.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('r_gun', $tarih);
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->row() : false;
}
```

view file

```
<?php if($randevular && $randevular->r_saat){ ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Dolu</button>
<?php } else { ?> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Müsait</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add more condition

```
<?php if(isset($randevular->r_saat)) { ?>
    <?php if($randevular->r_saat) { ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Dolu</button>
        <?php } else { ?> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Müsait</button>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed tablename for where `$this->db->where('tablename.r_gun', $tarih);`

```
public function denemelik($tarih){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('randevular');
    $this->db->join('hasta_karti', 'hasta_karti.id = randevular.h_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('randevular.r_gun', $tarih);

    $query= $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you know what happen on your code. You just need to add some logic to prevent the error happen.

You can use `!empty($randevular->r_saat)` or `isset($randevular->r_saat))` checking the object is defined or not. Based on [check out this comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

```
<?php if(!empty($randevular->r_saat)) { ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Dolu</button>
<?php } else { ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Müsait</button>
<?php } ?>
```